# Face Error uploading file: Upload session failed too many times when using "Site.Selected" Permission to upload file to Share Point in Java Program

Tags: java, azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a project which need to upload file to Selected Share Point Sites through client-credential.
I had apply a Site.Selected Application Permission on my APP and also grant the "write" role to it using Admin Azure AD.

```
 {

   "roles": ["write"],

   "grantedToIdentities": [{

     "application": {

     "id": "clientid",

     "displayName": "blobtest"

 }

}]

}
```

Below are the method to get the access token from provider

```
  public IGraphServiceClient getAuthProvider() {
    IAuthenticationProvider mAuthenticationProvider;
    try {
        String accessToken = getAuthToken();
        mAuthenticationProvider = request -> request.addHeader("Authorization",
                "Bearer " + accessToken);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Could not create a graph client: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    IGraphServiceClient graphClient =
            GraphServiceClient
                    .builder()
                    .authenticationProvider(mAuthenticationProvider)
                    .buildClient();

    return graphClient;
}
```

However, the upload was facing some issue at result below occur.

2021-05-05 20:28:24.137  INFO 2148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'

2021-05-05 20:28:24.147  INFO 2148 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms

Now try to connect to Share Point and upload testing_123.pdf, Please wait...

The Site's ID is: siteid-site-id-sharepoint-siteid

**Error uploading file: Upload session failed too many times.**

But this method is perfect to upload when I try use Site.ReadWrite.All Application Permission. Do anyone know how to solve this issue? The requirement is only allow to use Site.Selected instead other permission.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are requesting this endpoint to upload file to SharePoint.

```
POST /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession
```

If so, this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) **has to** use `Sites.ReadWrite.All` application permission.

[image]

Even though uploading file with another [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) which supports files up to 4MB in size, you also need  `Files.ReadWrite.All` or `Sites.ReadWrite.All` permission.

> **Sites.Selected:** Allow the application to access a subset of site collections without a signed in user.  The specific site collections
> and the permissions granted will be configured in SharePoint Online.
>
> **Sites.ReadWrite.All:** Allow the application to access a subset of site collections without a signed in user.  The specific site
> collections and the permissions granted will be configured in
> SharePoint Online.

Comment: Is  Sites.ReadWrite.All is necessary? Because if using Sites.ReadWrite.All, the program will able to access all sites. is that any method allow to upload file by having Site.selected permission only?

Comment: If using the Microsoft Graph API, it's necessary. Sites.Selected is not supported for this.

Comment: Hi, @BingHao. Does my reply help? If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.